# Mono fast cgi not working on nginx

Tags: nginx, asp.net, fastcgi, mono

I installed mono fast cgi for nginx following instructions on:
http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx but when i try to load test aspx file
i getting 502 error gateway,and following error in error log:
2011/11/28 18:49:51 [error] 5376#0: *6 upstream sent unexpected FastCGI record: 3 while reading response header from upstream, client: ipadress, server: ipadress, request: "GET /default.aspx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9999", host: "ipadress"
I tried different things to change but always same result,except maybe sometime in error log is number 1 or 3 instead 6.Nginx ver is 1.03 64 bit,mono and xsp latest versions.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured how problem was in xsp not properly configured,it was not connecting to installed mono.Nginx proxy works fine so nginx part it's resolved,but now i getting following error when loading following test aspx file:

`<html> <body bgcolor="yellow"> <center><h2>Hello ServerFault!</h2><p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
</center>
</body></html>`

Compilation Error

> Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Unexpected symbol `__output'
>   /default.aspx
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> gmcs /target:library /lib:"/usr/local/nginx/html/bin" /debug-
>   /optimize+ /warn:0
>   /out:"/tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/e96ac5a8/App_Web_2a0e1fec.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.IdentityModel/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel.Web/3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll"
>   /nowarn:0169  --
>   "/tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/e96ac5a8/App_Web_2a0e1fec_0.cs"
>
> /tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/e96ac5a8/App_Web_2a0e1fec_0.cs(81,1): error
>   CS1525: Unexpected symbol `__output'